# GeoLocator return only integer value of GPS coordinates in WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gps, windows-phone-8.1

I add to Geolocator PositionChanged event, but on WP8.1 emulator coordinates return only before point value.
For example

I create point 147.342, 120.543, but in geolocator coordinates are 147.0, 120.0

On WP 8.0 emulator all works perfect.

I try to reinstall system, but it doesnt helped me.

```
Geolocator Geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High, ReportInterval = 1000};
```

Also i run standart MAP application on emulator, and it also work same.

Comment: I've [tried sample code](http://1drv.ms/1mBFLVc) and seems to work fine. Maybe the problem is with other part of your code?

Comment: Problem with Emulator, because of standart application (not mine) also doesnt work. But i reinstall Windows, Install VS 2013 and then Update 2, but problem not solved.

Comment: Check whether you have proper internet connection in your emulator and check the app again and also the location should be turned on.

Comment: Internet connection is good. location is turned on.

Comment: Same problem here. Seems to be a machine/configuration/version issue, because the same code works on another machine as expected. But I didn't find the root cause yet.